# Find bipartite graph vertex cover with a Very Important Vertex

Tags: computer-science, graph-theory

I know that I can find the minimum vertex cover of a bipartite graph by first finding the maximum matching and then using [Konig's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29#Algorithm) to turn this matching into a vertex cover of the same order.

However, the result obtained is only one of what could be many valid vertex covers. In the following graph, {A,B}, {C,D}, and {B,C} are all valid covers. Applying the Konig method yields the cover {A,B}.

```
(A)=====(C)
       /
     /
   /
(B)=====(D)
```

How would you check for the existence of a minimum vertex cover that includes a given important vertex, say, vertex D?

My first guess is to *flip* the graph and find another minimum vertex cover. In the above case, this would yield {C,D}. If neither solution contains the important vertex, it's not part of any minimum cover.  However, I haven't thought deeply enough to really prove this to myself.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following method

1. Find the size of the minimum vertex cover (Let a vertex cover be $C$ )
2. Remove the "Very Important Vertex" and all the edges covered by the same (Vertex be $v$)
3. Repeat the process and let the new vertex cover be $C'$

If $|C' + V| = |C|$ then report the minimum vertex cover else report no minimum vertex cover exists with the given vertex.

I guess you have the same answer the proof is also along the same lines.

The new vertex cover cannot be smaller since it would violate the condition that $C$ was one of the minimum vertex cover.

Also $C'$ is the minimum cover covering the rest of the graph.

If there is atleast one minimum vertex cover including the vertex $V$ then the rest of the vertices in that set would cover all the vertices except the ones adjacent to $V$, but then it would mean that $|C'|$ is not larger than $|C|-1$ hence a faliure to do this would imply no minimum vertex cover exists including the VIP edge.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the initial matching using the Hungarian algorithm, giving a lower weight to all the edges ending in that vertex.